# VERTICA: changing projections

Tags: projection, vertica

I need to change super-projections in table (wrong order and segmentation).
So how I try to do it.

1. Rename existing projections:

   ```
   ALTER PROJECTION schema.table_b0 RENAME TO table_b0_2;
   ALTER PROJECTION schema.table_b1 RENAME TO table_b1_2;
   ```
2. Create new projections:

   ```
   CREATE PROJECTION schema.table
   as select * from schema.table
   order by ...
   segmented by hash (...) all nodes;
   ```
3. Refresh:

   ```
   select refresh('schema.table');
   ```
4. Drop old ones:

   ```
   DROP PROJECTION table_b0_2;
   DROP PROJECTION table_b1_2;
   ```

I guess it's almost what I want, but...

1. I get two projections with suffixes "_b0" and "_b1", but usually (if creation table have been done right) there is two projections with suffixes "_b0" and "_super". Why?
2. After that projection creation I can't drop table without `cascade` parameter in `drop table` statement. So I kinda get my projections as separeted objects. Is the anything I can fix that (to create projections as though they were created with right`create table` statement from the start)?

Answer (score 2):

1. It's just a name. When it creates a default superprojections, it names it `_super`. (I think this naming convention is new though). Default projections are not going to be optimal, and you'll want to replace them using DBD. I'm assuming you are already aware of b0 vs b1 and ksafety.
2. Default projects are objects you did not explicitly create. You can tell that these are default projections by looking at the `projections` view. They will say `DELAYED CREATION`.  Since you did not explicitly create them, Vertica allows them to be dropped with the table. If, however, you explicitly create a projection by hand or using DBD, it will require that you drop those first or use `cascade`.

A couple of notes. First, the create projection should be the projection name, not the table name.  You'll get an object already exists error if they are the same name. Second, before you drop the old projections, you may need to move the ancient history marker with `select make_ahm_now();`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer! First, what is DBD?) And about explicitly creation - if I create projections using `create table` statement (`create_type = "CREATE TABLE WITH PROJ CLAUSE"`) I will be able to drop the table without `cascade`.

Comment: @Vikora DBD is the Database Designer.  The two second introduction is... you load your table with representative data, you feed DBD your anticipated queries, and it will create optimized projections for you. I would always recommend starting with DBD and only customize when needed.

Comment: @Vikora Regarding the `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ... INCLUDING PROJECTIONS`, it will act the same as your original table. If your original table had custom or designer projections, it will consider those dependencies and require `CASCADE`.

Comment: @Vikora If you include Projection clauses on the `CREATE TABLE`  then, yes, you'll be able to drop without cascade. This is because in a way this is an implicit creation  (as in, not a separate `CREATE` statement). One thing I'm not sure I understand is maybe why the concern around using `CASCADE`?